# Embedded Set with Spring Roo (Scaffolding)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I am struggling to scaffold a Class with an „embedded List“.

I have a Product where a scaled Price should be persisted and scaffolded (MVC) within the Product-Class.

The Class for the scale price looks like this

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@Embeddable
public class ScalePrice {
    int from;
    int to;
    BigDecimal price;

}
```

And my naive implementation of the Product-Class looks like this:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class Product {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2)
    private String shortDescription;

    private String longDescription;

    @Embedded
    private Set<ScalePrice> scalePrices;
}
```

Since the List/Set for the Scale Price makes only sense for a particular product, the form should provide a way to enter the Scale Price directly within the product form.

My Question is: is this possible at all with Spring Roo? And if yes, how can this be accomplished?

Comment: Since only a particular product has a ScalePrice, why don't you integrate it into the product? If you want a separate ScalePrice class, why is there a 1:N cardinality between Product-ScalePrice? Shouldn't it be 1:1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring roo doesn't handle collections very well, so even if you had:

```
private Set<Integer> scalePrices;
```

You would not be able to enter multiple scalePrices on the one form.
You could write your own custom tag to support this kind of thing though.